# How do a join two columns into another seperate column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is probably easy, but im new to Python.
I want to add two columns which are Latitude and Longitude and put it into a column called Location.

For example:

First row in Latitude will have a value of `41.864073` and the first row of Longitude will have a value of `-87.706819`.

I would like the `'Locations'` column to display `41.864073, -87.706819`.

please and thank you.

Comment: Hey BIll. It looks like you got a bunch of answers. If the problem is solved, we  would appreciate if you selected one of the answers as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(lat=range(10, 20), lon=range(100, 110)))
```

---

#### `zip`

This should be better than using `apply`

```
df.assign(location=[*zip(df.lat, df.lon)])

   lat  lon   location
0   10  100  (10, 100)
1   11  101  (11, 101)
2   12  102  (12, 102)
3   13  103  (13, 103)
4   14  104  (14, 104)
5   15  105  (15, 105)
6   16  106  (16, 106)
7   17  107  (17, 107)
8   18  108  (18, 108)
9   19  109  (19, 109)
```

---

#### `list` variant

Though I'd still suggest `tuple`

```
df.assign(location=df[['lat', 'lon']].values.tolist())

   lat  lon   location
0   10  100  [10, 100]
1   11  101  [11, 101]
2   12  102  [12, 102]
3   13  103  [13, 103]
4   14  104  [14, 104]
5   15  105  [15, 105]
6   16  106  [16, 106]
7   17  107  [17, 107]
8   18  108  [18, 108]
9   19  109  [19, 109]
```

Comment: "This should be better than using `apply`" <- Can you please explain a bit more? Personally, I think `apply` is easier to read, is there a performance issue or something else I am missing?

Comment: `apply` is great particularly for the reason that it is very intuitive.  Therefore, if performance isn't an issue, it is a fine solution.  However, it is known that `apply` can have performance issues.  I try to avoid using a performance bludgeon for every question and answer but I do try to avoid using `apply` in my answers.  But I will admit that in some cases, it makes the answers more elegant.  Personally, I like zip.  It is a core component of the language and deserves understanding so that it too becomes "readable".

Answer (score 2):

I question the usefulness of this column, but you can generate it by applying the `tuple` callable over the columns.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3,4]], columns=['lon', 'lat'])
>>> df
>>> 
   lon  lat
0    1    2
1    3    4
>>> 
>>> df['Location'] = df.apply(tuple, axis=1)
>>> df
>>> 
   lon  lat Location
0    1    2   (1, 2)
1    3    4   (3, 4)
```

If there are other columns than `'lon'` and `'lat'` in your dataframe, use

```
df['Location'] = df[['lon', 'lat']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
```

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that I have other columns as well. When I tried what you suggested it added the other columns into location also. Anyway to specifically join lon & lat?

Answer (score 2):

Data from Pir

```
df['New']=tuple(zip(*df[['lat','lon']].values.T))
df
Out[106]: 
   lat  lon        New
0   10  100  (10, 100)
1   11  101  (11, 101)
2   12  102  (12, 102)
3   13  103  (13, 103)
4   14  104  (14, 104)
5   15  105  (15, 105)
6   16  106  (16, 106)
7   17  107  (17, 107)
8   18  108  (18, 108)
9   19  109  (19, 109)
```

Answer (score 0):

I definitely learned something from W-B and timgeb. My idea was to just convert to strings and concatenate. I posted my answer in case you wanted the result as a string. Otherwise it looks like the answers above are the way to go.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *  

Dic = {'Lattitude': [41.864073], 'Longitude': [-87.706819]}
DF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dic)
DF['Location'] = DF['Lattitude'].astype(str) + ',' +  DF['Longitude'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: OP does not state that they need to create a new dataframe.  I would not recommend the method you present.  You're creating 2 dictionaries then 2 dataframes only to join them together.  This is unnecessary.  However, none of the other answers mention actually joining as a string.  That is a valid interpretation but you are doing a lot of converting of types for very little benefit.  I'd recommend sticking with a tuple.

Comment: I see what you're saying piRSquared. The creation of the 2 dictionaries and 2 dataframes was to get to the point where I thought the OP was starting from. I updated my post to create 1 dictionary and 1 dataframe. I agree that your solution is much more elegant...just taking a stab at it with the arsenal I've learned up to this point lol.